# Formulário fazendo INSERT vazio no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou criando uma página de cadastro simples e criei um Form para armazenar o que foi digitado no Banco de Dados. Entretanto, mesmo com a validação do Form em PHP para ver se tem algum campo vazio, quando eu clico em Cadastrar, ele armazena dados em branco no Banco de Dados. Vocês poderiam me dar uma mão nesse caso?

Este é o formulário em html e as validações dos campos em PHP.

```
<form method="post" name="formCadastro" action="inserir_dados.php" >

            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Seu nome completo"

                    <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['value_nome'])){
                            echo "value='".$_SESSION['value_nome']."'";
                            unset($_SESSION['value_nome']);
                        }
                     ?>>
                     <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['vazio_nome'])){
                            echo "<p style='color: #b63e3e;position: relative; top:43px'>".$_SESSION['vazio_nome']."</p>";
                            unset($_SESSION['vazio_nome']);
                        }
                     ?>             

            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email comercial"

                    <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['value_email'])){
                            echo "value='".$_SESSION['value_email']."'";
                            unset($_SESSION['value_email']);
                        }
                     ?>>
                     <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['vazio_email'])){
                            echo "<p style='color: #b63e3e;position: relative; top:43px'>".$_SESSION['vazio_email']."</p>";
                            unset($_SESSION['vazio_email']);
                        }
                     ?>                     

            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" id ="fone" name="fone" placeholder="Telefone com DDD"

                    <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['value_fone'])){
                            echo "value='".$_SESSION['value_fone']."'";
                            unset($_SESSION['value_fone']);
                        }
                     ?>>
                     <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['vazio_fone'])){
                            echo "<p style='font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #b63e3e;position: relative; top:43px'>".$_SESSION['vazio_fone']."</p>";
                            unset($_SESSION['vazio_fone']);
                        }
                     ?>     

            <br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">

        </form>
```

Aqui é o código para armazenar no BD.

```
<?php
```

session_start();

```
include_once 'conexao.php';

$nome = null;
$email = null;
$fone = null;

if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
    $_SESSION['vazio_nome'] = "Campo nome é obrigatório";
    $url = 'index.php';
    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$url'>
    ";
}else{
    $_SESSION['value_nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
}

if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    $_SESSION['vazio_email'] = "Campo e-mail é obrigatório";
    $url = 'index.php';
    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$url'>
    ";
}else{
    $_SESSION['value_email'] = $_POST['email'];
}

if(empty($_POST['fone'])){
    $_SESSION['vazio_fone'] = "Campo e-mail é obrigatório";
    $url = 'index.php';
    echo "
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$url'>
    ";
}else{
    $_SESSION['value_fone'] = $_POST['fone'];
}

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['nome']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['email']);
$fone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['fone']);

$result_sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (nome,email,fone) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$fone')";

$resultado_sql= mysqli_query($conexao, $result_sql);

if($conexao->query($result_sql) == TRUE){
    echo "Usuário OK";      
}else{
    echo "Erro".$result_sql."<br>".$conexao->error;
        }
$conexao->close();
```

?>

Comment: Na tabela do seu banco de dados, pelo menos um campo deveria ser `não nulo` por exemplo o campo nome. Isso já resolveria muita coisa!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> O seu formulário HTML está correto, dentro do que você se propôs a fazer.

só falta você colocar `session_start();` na primeira linha e corrigir

```
$_SESSION['vazio_fone'] = "Campo telefone é obrigatório";
```

**Já na página PHP inserir_dados.php  você faz a validação dos dados do lado servidor**.

```
if(empty($_POST['nome'])){..  if(empty($_POST['email'])){ ..  if(empty($_POST['fone'])){...
```

Até ai tudo bem. Só que o script PHP continua sendo executado e vai ao encontro do insert.

Como nenhuma restrição foi imposta, o insert vai ser executado de qualquer forma, isto é, se foram ou não enviados os campos do formulário.

Você pode impedir que o script continue sendo executado simplesmente colocando `exit();` após os metas refresh

`echo("<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$url'>");
 exit();`

**Esse trecho de código** `$resultado_sql= mysqli_query($conexao, $result_sql);` **está sobrando e fazendo insert repetido no banco.**

> Você poderá gostar desse modelo ao invés de usar exit();

Repare que se algum dado não foi enviado é criado uma variável `$insert="nananinanao";`

É essa variável que vai impedir o insert na tabela caso algum dado não seja passado

**inserir_dados.php**

```
session_start();

include_once 'conexao.php';

$nome = null;
$email = null;
$fone = null;

  if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
       $_SESSION['vazio_nome'] = "Campo nome é obrigatório";
       $insert="nananinanao";
  }else{
       $_SESSION['value_nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
  }

  if(empty($_POST['email'])){
       $_SESSION['vazio_email'] = "Campo e-mail é obrigatório";
       $insert="nananinanao";
  }else{
       $_SESSION['value_email'] = $_POST['email'];
   }

   if(empty($_POST['fone'])){
       $_SESSION['vazio_fone'] = "Campo e-mail é obrigatório";
       $insert="nananinanao";
   }else{
       $_SESSION['value_fone'] = $_POST['fone'];
   }

   if ($insert!="nananinanao"){
       $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['nome']);
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['email']);
       $fone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['fone']);

       $result_sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (nome,email,fone) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$fone')";

    }else{
        $url = 'index.php';
        echo("<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$url'>");
        exit();
    }

    if($conexao->query($result_sql) == TRUE){
         echo "Usuário OK";      
    }else{
         echo "Erro".$result_sql."<br>".$conexao->error;
    }
    $conexao->close();
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações que você sugeriu e funcionou perfeitamente aqui, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A validação pelo PHP de um formulário, deve ser feita no servidor e não vai funcionar porque você a colocou no lado cliente. Do lado cliente, você deve usar o javascript para fazer a validação.

Considerando que a validação do lado cliente não é totalmente confiável, você deve fazer novamente no servidor, antes de salvar as informações no banco de dados.

Você pode fazer apenas um arquivo PHP que englobe todos os itens, isto é, o form., a validação cliente (javascript), a validação no servidor (PHP), a gravação dos dados e as mensagens de erro.

Você também pode fazer a validação apenas no servidor (PHP), omitindio-a do cliente. O contrário não é recomendado.